# Why is my github.io react-gh-pages showing a 404?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Im using react to publish to gh pages, and its giving me a 404 despite my other one ryan-howard-hc.github.io/ReactMenu working from the same tutorial video?

https://github.com/ryan-howard-hc/ryan-howard-hc.github.io

Here is the repo, It's giving me a 404 and Ive tried everything I can think of and have compared to my other repo ReactMenu

I followed the same method to deploy that. I thought it had something to do with the fact its the homepage
ryan-howard-hc.github.io but I have no idea. Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU6iy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only uploaded the source code in your GitHub repository and it will not work.

If you want to deploy a react website to GitHub pages then follow this:

#### ***Method 1: Manual Deployment***

1. Run this command in your terminal:

```bash
cd /change/this/to/your/project/root/directory/path/
npm run build
```

2. Then from your build folder upload all files to the GitHub repository. Only upload the content inside the build folder,

#### ***Method 2: Direct Deployment***

1. Add the `gh-pages` package to your project

```bash
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

2. On your package.json file inside scripts add `predeploy` and `deploy` properties.

```
"scripts": {
  "predeploy": "npm run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
}
```

3. Now add a remote git repository to your project:
   change the `username` and `repo-name`

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/{username}/{repo-name}.git
```

4. Now push your react app to the GitHub repository

```
npm run deploy
```

5. Finally, when you want to configure the subdomain go to setting and select the branch as `gh-pages` and root as `/`

And now if you have followed any of this 2 method your react app will be successfully deployed to the GitHub pages.

Comment: Edit: I swear I have done all of this... Thank you udoyhasan!

Comment: @RyanHoward glad to know that it helped you :)